# Google Play App Installs/Downloads Reduced Compare to 2014

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I need some help regarding Google Play App Installs/Downloads. We are publishing apps in Google Play from 2013. We will promote our app after Publishing the app in Google Play. When App will get listed in "Top New Free Android Apps" in Google Play, We will stop promoting. From then, App will get Good Number of Installs/Downloads. But From Mid 2015, This is not happening. App downloads are very very low even it Reach 50th Position in "Top New Free Android Apps". I've searched a lot on this issue but no use. Anybody know why this is happening. If you know, I am kindly requesting you to share that information. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm too have same issue and all developers have it. The reason because of new Google play store in the new design the user should click a small button " Top charts" then swipe to reach " top new free" but in the old design the user only swipe to reach " top new free" so old design is more simple to the user also there is another reason preventing the user from reaching " top new free" because in Google play store first page ( homepage) there is tons of apps and games so the user will be busy surfing it and rarly click the small " top charts" button then swipe to reach " top new free" so the problem is entirly from Google play store new design